# When do I play with the full board in Neuroshima Hex?

Tags: neuroshima-hex

I have just bought Neuroshima Hex and read the rulebook. It mentions just using the hexes in the centre of the board, but that the other spaces around the outside are included incase a scenario is played. What are these scenarios? And will I need to use the bigger board in a 3 or 4 player game?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking through the [Neuroshima Hex 3.0 rules (pdf)](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Neuroshima_Hex_3.pdf), I see the following:

[image: Neurosihma Hex board layout]

So the extra hexes are for when there are five to six people playing. The rules suggest that if there are four people playing, you might decide to use the expanded board as well.

This rule book doesn't mention scenarios. However, I looked up one of the expansions: [Neuroshima Hex: Babel 13 (pdf)](http://zmangames.com/rulebooks/Neuroshima_Hex_Babel13.pdf), and it mentions scenarios:

> A Neuroshima Hex scenario is a single game which applies additional conditions to the basic rules of the game. These can include Terrain, unequal distribution of forces, conditional events, etc. Campaigns for Neuroshima Hex consist of a series of interrelated scenarios.

This would imply that a scenario might make use of the extra hexes for, perhaps, unequal distribution of forces.